# Is Interval okay for database like this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im trying to get last id from table as realtime, and Im using interval.
I know that Interval is something not good for database, but there is some difference in this code,
because load() function loads the div. Not backend codes.

So my question is: is it effective for use less query for db?

```
<?php
$lastid=$db->prepare("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM names");
$lastid->execute(); $last=$lastid->fetch();
?>

<div id="last">
<?php echo $last['id']; ?>
</div>

<script>

    setInterval(function(){

    $('#last').load(location.href + ' #last');

    },1000);

</script>
```

Comment: basically, it's a matter of how much hardware you throw at the problem. you might work with long polling to reduce load on the webserver.

Comment: @franz-gleichmann Should I install nodejs etc. stuffs for long polling?

Comment: Keep in mind that you're loading the _entire_ page into the div, including another copy of the div, and another copy of the Javascript

Comment: This might be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why do you need the last ID in real time? What are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @VLAZ I will call that page via get method, if last ID is greater than the id before last ID, it will refresh the chat conversation that I called the get for.

Comment: So, you're just doing an update heartbeat? I don't see why you need to be constantly fetching the last ID - you usually just send the server the timestamp of the last thing you've seen and then it sends you anything new. Or it just sends you everything each time. Or it pushes notifications to you. That's the usualy way to handle it - if you're getting the last ID to check whether you need to fetch more, that's doing more work than just "I've last seen X" and the server responding with either nothing or "Here is Y and Z".

Comment: @lolosoft If this is a chat application then this is the wrong pattern.  Yes I think you should look into NodeJS - there is lots of tutorials on building a chat app.  It's a more appropriate technology.  Polling the database will not scale.

Comment: Yes, I exactly do the thing you say, because more data is more traffic for db. And only "1" is enough for show everything to the users. Im doing that this method because Im foreign to the nodejs and websockets. So; Im trying to create new methods about realtime without any server side.

Comment: You say that sending a single integer is faster but I don't think you take into consideration the fact that to get an update you need to make *at least three* roundtrips to the database plus all the network requests from the client to the server. Just the DB requests are 1. Get max ID 2. Get max ID which is higher  3. Ask for more data. Sending a single integer doesn't decrease the cumulative time you'd spend in roundtrips to the DB. You can dramatically shorten this to just "Ask for more data" every time or even better - just push updates to the client automatically.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for information, but I cant find a simple way to push anything to client from server. Im a new student about server side and nodejs. I want to ask you; Is there any way without server side installation to long polling and get any data as realtime?

Comment: "*without server side installation*" - where do you think your php code is running?